# CPU works louder when I am plugging my laptop in

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, clockspeed, core

I noticed that my CPU works louder when I am plugging my laptop in. 
I am using an HWMonitor Version 1.40.0 Driver version 148 to check my status of CPU. 
I am worried that my laptop can be damaged soon. HWMonitor shows or my every core there is a Value around 3600 - 3900 MHz.
When I am disconnecting my power supply from the socket HWMonitor shows 690 - 980 MHz.
It's a big difference.

Is it something wrong with my laptop, power supply or maybe there is something wrong with my an electrical installation at home?

What should I check or fix?

Comment: *"my CPU works louder "* -- A CPU has no moving parts, and is silent.  The sound is probably from the fan(s) and air turbulence.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didnt list your laptop's model, I cant say with the following with 100% certainty.  However, it is very highly probable to be correct.

Your laptop is working absolutely as it should.  3.9 GHz (3900 MHz) is a typical speed for a modern CPU, including its cores.  When plugged into an AC outlet, your laptop will run faster.  When unplugged, laptops often slow down the CPU to last longer on batteries.  The laptop can scale the CPU power up as needed as well.  Naturally, at full power, the CPU generates a lot of heat and the fans run at high speed to cool it.  The fans spinning is the sound you hear.  Again, this is absolutely normal and safe.

However, if the machine is *constantly* running at 100% CPU usage, there very well may be an issue.

Comment: My laptop's model is Lenovo T580 with Intel Core i7-8550 CPU @ 1.80GHz

Comment: @stardustsky All you had to do was google the CPU model #.  It goes up to 4 GHz.

Comment: Ok, I would understand if this noise would not be all the time when my laptop is plugged into an AC outlet. I think that it should be only from time to time when my battery is low. If the buttery is fully charged it should be stopped.


This kind of issue reduces the comfort of work on the laptop by the following noise.